# Sharepoint 2007 MOSS Search Administration Does not Appear Connected to WSS_Search_

Tags: 2007, search

First time here.  It looks like you folks have a great handle on SharePoint.  I hope you can help:
1.  I have a 2 server system WFE (DC) also handles search and query and LDAP.  SharePoint 2007 MOSS SP2.  Second server SQL 2005.  Both server are running server 2003.

1. A week ago I had a hard drive failure on a secondary drive (D) on the WFE.  The drive housed the SSP (SharedServices1) index among a couple of other items.  The drive data was recovered  to a new partition (D) on a new WFE Primary drive.
2. Although (at first) all systems seemed to work perfectly.  Within a couple of days it was noticed that search was broken.
3. I have been trying (to no avail) to restore the proper functioning of the search function.  However, I seem to be at my capability limits.
   a.  I am able to see all the content sources through Search Administration.
   b.  I have reset all the initial crawled content
   c.  All DB Tables are listed as Ready
   d.  Each time I attempt to start a full crawl..  It identifies it is in "full crawl" mode and as I refresh after a couple of seconds it reads "Idle"
   e.  No crawl logs are generated.  And, no results are returned.
4. It appears that I am having a permissioning issue.  With this in mind I have:
   a.  Added permissions (full control) to the new share  and for OSearch on Component services (Launch and Activation):
       i.   Local Admins
       Ii.  WSS_Admin_WPG and WSS_WPG
       Iii.  I've recycled all the services, i.e., Timer, Search and Administration /iisreset and finally rebooted many times.
       Iv.  I am able to reach http://:56737/SharedServices1/search/SearchAdmin.asmx WebServices page
       Iv.  However, I cannot reach the  http://:56737/SearchAdmin.asmx site and continually get a 401 error.  A proposed solution  was to modify the root web.config containin an incorrect reference to the authorized user, i.e. ".\WSS_Admin_WPG".  Upon substituting  for the "." I am able to gain access.  However, the file is restored each time the timer runs.  I have been unable to find the source of the issue.  Perhaps this would solve the issues but at this time I am stumped.
5. I have been at this for MANY days without resolution.  I wonder if anyone here can shed some light on another angle.  I fear that I am too close to the problem and cannot see the forest for the weeds.
6. Any help  would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help,
Gus